# The z-index property is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a site in which I need hearts. I create the hearts using JavaScript and CSS:

```
function heart(x, y, pos, width, r) {
    var height = width + (width / 2 + 1);
    var heart = "position:" + pos + ";left:" + x + "px;top:" + y + "px;width:" + width + "px;height:" + height + "px;transform: rotate(" + r + "deg);-moz-transform: rotate(" + r + "deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(" + r + "deg);";
    var slices = "left:" + width + "px;width:" + width + "px;height:" + height + "px";
    $("body").append('<div class="heart" style="' + heart + '"><div class="slice" style="' + slices + '"></div><div class="slice2" style="' + slices + '"></div></div>');
}
```

I'm currently trying to put a large heart under a box using:

```
heart(282, 69, "absolute", 230, 0);
```

However, `z-index` is not doing anything, as you can see in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/NnFSP/show/) example.

I've even tried setting the `z-index` of the universal selector (*) to 0 while changing the `z-index` of the box to `10 !important;` but that didn't work either. I am puzzled about why this is happening, but I'm pretty sure it has to do with the dynamic heart. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element needs to be positioned in order for the `z-index` to work. See the [visual formatting modal](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index).

In this instance, you could simply add `position:relative` to the box.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtx6C/)

```
.welcome {
    z-index:10;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
}
```

No need for `!important` either.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `z-index`, your `<div>`s can't be `position: static;` (which is the default)

So in order to display the `.welcome` above the hearts you need to add `position:relative;`

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your z-index is not working because your `.welcome` box has a static positioning, so your

```
.welcome { z-index: 10 !important }
```

declaration is not having any effect. Because of this, the hearts, that have `z-index:0`, will still be on top.

**To fix this, either**

**a)** set the hearts to `z-index: -1`

```
.heart { z-index: -1 }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NnFSP/1/)

**b)** set `.welcome`'s `position` to something different than it's initial static position.

```
.welcome { position: relative }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NnFSP/2/)

And lose the `!important`, that's bad practice.

Comment: +1 For the quick answer + the `z-index: -1` solution c:

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be absolutely positioned. Relative positioning may be more practical and it will suffice in this instance. Of course, either work, it just needs something aside from `static`..

Comment: it needs position relative, not absolute to be effective