# Z-Index doesnt work on div box

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIV boxes. I want that 1 box overlap the other box.
The website is: https://goo.gl/KhJVxU

I used on the box "navigationsleiste" the following css code:
    .navigationsleiste {z-index:999;}

And for the box "Slider" this css Code:
    .sliderbox {z-index:1;}

but its doesnt work..

Comment: The element needs to be positioned in order for the `z-index` to have an effect. You could add `position: relative`. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394432/the-z-index-property-is-not-behaving-as-expected).

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

The `z-index` property only works when the property `position` it's different from 'static'.

ie:

```
/*********** will work */
.box1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.box2 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

/*********** won't work */
.box1 {
    z-index: 1;
}
.box2 {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 9 seconds. Damn ninjas. Deleted mine, enjoy your beer >=@

Comment: Noob failure... Thank you ;)